# System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method

Tags: batch-file, triggers, salesforce, apex

Getting the following error while updating a record via an external app.
The trigger is calling a batch when this record is getting updated.

```
Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0013H000008gq59QAA; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, ivybat.AccountOperation: execution of AfterUpdate

caused by: System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.

Trigger.ivybat.AccountOperation: line 121, column 1: []
```

Also getting the following error description recorded in one of the custom objects primarily created to log the errors while updating/inserting from the external app.

```
Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0013H000008gq59QAA; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, ivybat.AccountOperation: execution of AfterUpdate

caused by: System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.

Trigger.ivybat.AccountOperation: line 121, column 1: []
```

Debugging the class mentioned in the error description, found the recursion is happening.
So I had tried to stop the recursion but still facing the same issue.

I am not going through the solution suggested in the following blog for **System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.** as this is not throwing any issue in other orgs which are using the same managed package.

attaching the following block of code from the Trigger

```
if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isafter)
        {
            Map<String, Boolean> triggerLogicMap = TriggerLogicService.getDuplicationCheck(new Set<String>{'SKIP_AccountUpdate_Operation'});
            if(triggerLogicMap.get('SKIP_AccountUpdate_Operation') == Null 
               || triggerLogicMap.get('SKIP_AccountUpdate_Operation') == false) {
                   AccountOperationTriggerHelper.updateSalesOrgKey(trigger.new);        //    method calling to set SalesOrg key and tax classification key
                   Set<Id> accId = new Set<Id>();
                   Set<String> endMkts = new Set<String>();
                   map<Id,String> accmap = new map<id,String>();
                   boolean isReactivated = false;
                   for(Account acc : trigger.new){
                       system.debug(acc.ivybase__Status__c);
                       system.debug(trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).ivybase__Status__c);
                       if(acc.ivybase__Status__c != null && acc.ivybase__Status__c.equals('Active') && (acc.ivybase__Status__c != trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).ivybase__Status__c)){
                           isReactivated = true;
                           accmap.put(acc.Id,acc.market_iso__c);
                           accid.add(acc.id);
                       }
                   }
                   
                   if(isReactivated && (accId.size() > 0)){
                       if(!RoutePlanDetailsService.firstRun){
                           RoutePlanDetailsService.firstRun = true;
                           System.debug('Run the batch clas');
                           batchCalVisitRecords br = new batchCalVisitRecords(accId);
                           database.executeBatch(br);
                       }
                       
                   }
                   if(isReactivated && (accmap != null)){
                       CampaignTriggerHelper.insertvfonACCReactivation(accmap);
                   }
               }
        }
```

What would be suggested in such a scenario?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You appear to have used the term `batch`, and used the tag [[tag:batch-file]], however, I cannot see any batch file code in your question, or any reference to a file with a `.bat` or `.cmd` extension, which would indicate the use of one. Could you please clarify your questions' relationship to that used tag? _(Please feel free to hover over, or click on, the batch-file tag, to get a description of its use throughout this site.)_